# can we do sqoop import into hive external table?

Tags: hive, sqoop

```
sqoop import \
  --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@db1icvp.supermedia.com:1521:ICVP \
  --username=USER --password=password  \
  --table table_name \
  --split-by col_name --verbose \
  --hive-import \
  --hive-overwrite \
  --hive-table schema .table_name \
  --hive-home /path
```

Using above command I can create internal table only.
But my requirement is to create external table in a specific location using above commands..

Please suggest.

Comment: `sqoop` has `--target-dir` option.

Comment: is it really working?

Comment: I'm using it along with hcatalog integration, it works fine. -hcatalog-table and other hcatalog options. Didn't try it without hcatalog. See here: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.0/bk_data-movement-and-integration/content/sqoop_hcatalog_integration.html

Comment: It may depend on your sqoop version

Comment: sqoop version is 1.4.6.